# How to replace text in hompage only

Tags: the-content, homepage

I have a wordpress site with the 10 latest posts shown on the homepage.

I need to modify some text (because of duplicate content) on homepage but not on post page.

I try to modify the following line in index.php like this :

```
php the_content(Read more ...');

php the_content(Read more ...') . $content = str_replace('XXX', 'YYY');
```

But it's not working and i can't find a solution.

Can anybody help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`the_content(Read more ...')` echoes the stuff straight out so you can't modify it with `str_replace` after the fact.

If you wanna use `str_replace` you need to do something along the lines of

```
   $content = get_the_content( 'Read more ...' );
   $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
   $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
   $content = str_replace( 'xxx', 'yyy', $content );
   echo $content;
```

and replace xxx and yyy with the real stuff ofc.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution here is the working code :

```
   $content = get_the_content( 'Read more ...' );
   $content = str_replace( 'XXX', 'YYY', $content );
   echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

Thank you.